# Using variables to build fragment name in th:include - ThymeLeaf + Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to use the `fragment` functionality without the `th:fragment` (just using id). And in my code, the target fragment to be included is dynamically built from an iterator. The problem is creating the proper expression for the `th:include` to be rendered correctly. I've tried Concatenation, Preprocessing and Literal Substitution as per the tutorial, but without result - makes me think - is this allowed in `th:include`?

Fragment definition (It's in a file called `Comments.html` under my template, with my other templates).

```
<div id="LOW_SCORE_COMMENT">
```

It's been called this way

```
<div class="well" th:each="commentFragment : ${allComments}">
    <div th:include="'Comments :: #' + {__${commentFragment}__}">
    </div>          
</div>
```

`allComments` is an `Iterator<String>`, and the Strings retrieved are the fragment id's, so it should then build out the entire page.
But I get this error

> `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "'Comments", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Note the single quote between " and Comments in the error message.

Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT:
i tried this code

`<div class="well" th:each="commentFragment,iterstat : ${allComments}">
        <div th:include="${commentFragment.getValue()}"></div>`

essentially changed `allcomments` to a `TreeMap` to solve ordering issues, but now the error is as follows:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template
>   "Comments :: #LOW_SCORE_COMMENT", template might not exist or might not be >accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: It seems that you misuse `th:include`. From the docs about `th:include`: The first part of the statement is a template name that we are referencing. The expression after double colon is a fragment selector (either fragment name or DOM selector). But in your code it's all mixed up.

Comment: if, as above, my fragment is `<div id="LOW_SCORE_COMMENT">` and `${commentFragment}` resolves to LOW_SCORE_COMMENT, shouldn't it be read as `th:include= "Comments :: #LOW_SCORE_COMMENT"` .could you explain what you mean by mixed up? I'm referring to the Using Thymeleaf guide Section 8 Referencing fragments without th:fragment

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in missing preprocessing symbols `__` - see the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing). The expression without `__` is just replaced as is and passed to the resulting HTML page.

> Preprocessing is an execution of the expressions done before the normal one that allows for modification of the expression that will eventually be executed.
>
> Preprocessed expressions are exactly like normal ones, but appear surrounded by a double underscore symbol (like `__${expression}__`).

The correct working code is this:

```
<div class="well" th:each="commentFragment : ${allComments}">
    <div th:include="__${commentFragment.getValue()}__"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work using fragment expression as explained [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451)

```
<div class="well" th:each="commentFragment : ${allComments}">
  <div th:include="~{Comments :: #__${commentFragment}__}">
  </div>          
 </div>
```